# Return a string from MVC Controller to jQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to make a call to an ASP.NET MVC4 Controller and have it return a string to a jQuery method, then output that string with an alert(). The code below only outputs `object Object`.

jQuery:

```
$launchTRs = function (appID) {
    var html = $.get("/PartialView/GetTRAsString?appID=" + appID, function (data) { });
    alert(html.toString());
}
```

ASP:

```
public string GetTRAsString(string appID)
{
    // Populate revisions
    string html = "<ul>";

    foreach(RevesionInfo revInfo in revisions)
    {
        html += "<li>" + revInfo.RevDesc + "</li>";
    }

    html += "</ul>";

    return html;
}
```

Outut:

```
[object Object]
```

Comment: Learn how to use jQuery ajax: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

Comment: Agreed. This a simple case of you just not even reading the jQuery docs. StackOverflow is not the alternative for TL;DR.

Comment: @ChrisPratt, I can't really  laugh out loud 'cause I'll disturb my office mates, but this is brilliant! This should be the SO motto:  **StackOverflow is not the alternative for TL;DR**.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In ASP.NET MVC controller actions do not return strings. They return ActionResults.

So start by *fixing* your action (read below to understand why I put fixing in italic, it's because that's only the first stage):

```
public ActionResult GetTRAsString(string appID)
{
    // Populate revisions
    string html = "<ul>";

    foreach(RevesionInfo revInfo in revisions)
    {
        html += "<li>" + revInfo.RevDesc + "</li>";
    }

    html += "</ul>";

    return Content(html, "text/html");
}
```

Also the first A letter in AJAX stands for Asynchronous, so you should put the alert inside your success callback, which is the only place where the result will be available:

```
$.get('/PartialView/GetTRAsString', { appID: appID }, function (data) { 
    alert(data);
});
```

Also bear in mind that generating HTML in a controller action is a terrible idea. Mixing C# and HTML leads to ugliness that I prefer not to comment.

In ASP.NET MVC, the `V` stands for View, so go ahead, use them. The purpose of a controller action is to fetch a model and pass this model to the view in order to project it:

```
public ActionResult GetTRAsString(string appID)
{
    IEnumerable<Revision> revisions = ... go get your revisions from the DB or something
    return PartialView(revisions);
}
```

and then your view will be strongly typed to the model and you will generate the necessary markup inside:

```
@model IEnumerable<Revision>
<ul>
    @foreach (var revInfo in Model)
    {
        <li>
            @revInfo.RevDesc
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

Comment: I have a question on your comment `Mixing C# and HTML leads to ugliness that I prefer not to comment.` doesn't the inbuilt `HTML helpers` do the same?

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
var html = "";
$.ajax({
    url: "/PartialView/GetTRAsString",
    method: 'GET',
    data: {appId: appID },
    success: (resp){
        html = resp.html;
    }
});
```

Then your action method will be:

```
public JsonResult GetTRAsString(string appID)
{
    // Populate revisions
    string html = "<ul>";

    foreach(RevesionInfo revInfo in revisions)
    {
        html += "<li>" + revInfo.RevDesc + "</li>";
    }

    html += "</ul>";

    return Json(new {html});
}
```

Answer (score 8):

One more solution using AJAX -

Controller Action -

```
    public ActionResult GetString(string input)
    {
        return Content(input + ", Hello!!!");
    }
```

View -

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#click1').click(function (e) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "@Url.Action("GetString")",
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    input: 'John'
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                },
                success: function (response) {
                    alert(response);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
<input type="button" value="Click Me" id="click1" />
```

And when you click -

[image]

Comment: The alert always comes from the error, because it's expecting json.  Remove the line: dataType: "json", and in the controller instead return Content(input + ", Hello!!!", "text/html"); and the alert will come from the success.

Answer (score 1):

Will suggest to return JSONResult, as it's most common practice for such cases + use templating engine, like Mustache, or what ever else, rather then just fill handmade template within values on server side.

like this:

server stuff:

```
public JSONResult ActionName()
{
   var result=new { Success="False", Message="Error Message"};
   return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

client stuff:

```
var template = "<h1>{{your property values here}}</h1>", 
    html = '';

$('#sampleArea').html(html);
    $.getJSON('YourController/ActionName', function(data) {
         html = Mustache.to_html(template, data);
    });
```

more information above:

1. http://coenraets.org/blog/2011/12/tutorial-html-templates-with-mustache-js/
2. http://shashankshetty.wordpress.com/2009/03/04/using-jsonresult-with-jquery-in-aspnet-mvc/